# How to retrieve weather data in json [android]

Tags: java, android, json

I want to retrieve weather data from an API as JSON, but it isn't working. How do I pull in weather data, such as a 5-day forecast, into a text view?

My code is below, but I need to somehow adapt it to pass in the JSON 5-day weather forecast and put that into a text view.

```java
package mytweets.mytweets;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MytweetsActivity extends Activity {

    // we are reading weathe

    final String URL `enter code here`="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q,gb&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=5&APPID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    final String Consumer_Key = "mPfkAwVuuiVYeuZWdHAMzQ";  // change this if it does not work, you can get this from your twitter account at https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new
    final String Consumer_Secret = "bkmiQqellGg9jnJFj41E8zukYSNk0FX1W7v1nU376rE"; // change this if it does not work, you can get this from your twitter account at https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

    JSONArray tweets = null; //an array of tweets


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mytweets);

        Button btn_token = (Button)findViewById(R.id.get_token);
        btn_token.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new GetTokenTask().execute();
            }
            });

        Button btn_feed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.get_tweets);
        btn_feed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView txt_token = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_token);
                String token = txt_token.getText().toString();
                new GetTweetsTask().execute(token, URL);
            }
            });
    }

    protected class GetTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {  // the class extends AsynTask in order to run as a thread in the background

        @Override
        protected String d    
            try {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");  //asks for a token

                    String apiString = Consumer_Key + ":" + Consumer_Secret;
                    String authorization = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(apiString.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);  // twitter ants the authorization in bytes

                    httppost.setHeader("Authorization", authorization);
                    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials"));

                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8); // reading the input stream
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    return sb.toString();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("GetTokenTask", "Error:" + e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String jsonText){
                try {
                    JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonText);
                    String bearer_token = root.getString("access_token");

                    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_token);
                    txt.setText(bearer_token);    
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("GetTokenTask", "Error:" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }  

        protected class GetTweetsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {   //the class is run as a thread in the background to get the tweets

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                try {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(params[1]);
                    httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + params[0]);

                    httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");   //json content type

                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    return sb.toString();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("GetFeedTask", "Error:" + e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString){
                try {
                    TextView txt_tweets = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_tweets);

                    JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                    JSONArray forecastArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray("list");

                    String txt = "";

                    int i;

                    double minTemp, maxTemp;

                    // we are going to parse the json string and only display created_at and text. You can decide to display more objects if you want.
                    for (i=0;i<tweets.length();i++)
                    {

                            JSONObject dailyForecast = forecastArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject tempObject = dailyForecast.getJSONObject("temp");
                            minTemp = tempObject.getDouble("min");
                            maxTemp = tempObject.getDouble("max");
                            //add these minTemp and maxTemp to array or the
                            //way you want to use


                        txt_tweets.setText(txt);

                        txt += "------------\n";  //separtors, check the output


                    }



                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("GetFeedTask", "Error:" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mytweets, menu);
            return true;

        }    

    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Whats the error message you get?

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, basically I want the 5 day forecast to be displayed in the text view called text tweets. So far I am just trying to get temperature to be passed in from JSOn open weather api, then once this works I can implement the full 5 day weather forecast. Therefore please could you or someone else help me work out how to parse and read the json from openweather api into the app. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to help. But your question is too broad. What happens when you run your code? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't see code that calls your AsyncTask? Put something like `ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask asyncRequest = new ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask(URL, null, null);
            asyncRequest.execute();` in your code. E.g. in `onCreate `. Then at least your request should start.

Comment: Thanks,  sorry about my poor explanation, basically it doesn't parse the json information into the text box, although I will try all of your suggestions thanks for the help so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the JSON format of weather data:

```
city: {
id: 2643743,
name: "London",
coord: {
lon: -0.12574,
lat: 51.50853
},
country: "GB",
population: 0
},
cod: "200",
message: 0.0268,
cnt: 5,
list: [
{
dt: 1448535600,
temp: {
day: 8.58,
min: 8.58,
max: 9.18,
night: 9.18,
eve: 8.58,
morn: 8.58
},
pressure: 1025.14,
humidity: 95,
weather: [
{
id: 500,
main: "Rain",
description: "light rain",
icon: "10d"
}
],
speed: 3.67,
deg: 224,
clouds: 92,
rain: 0.35
},
{},
{},
{},
{}
]
```

Now to access the weather data (e.g. min and max temp) you need to parse as below:

```
JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray forecastArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray("list");
double minTemp, maxTemp;
for(int i = 0; i < forecastArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject dailyForecast = forecastArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject tempObject = dailyForecast.getJSONObject("temp");
    minTemp = tempObject.getDouble("min");
    maxTemp = tempObject.getDouble("max");
    //add these minTemp and maxTemp to array or the 
   //way you want to use
}
```

If you have further doubts, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i must be missing something it still doesn't work i need to somehow make the get _weather buttion perfrom the process. i have added that code you suggested under string=text ""

Comment: Thanks very much for your help so i guess something like this  JSONObject c = tweets.getJSONObject(i);

                        txt += "------------\n";  //separtors, check the output
                        txt += "temp:" + c.getString("temp") + "\n"; //getting weather temp

Comment: If you elaborate what problem you are facing then I can try to assist. One more point, you pasted your api key in the code snippet, never share your api key to public forum. I have edited and masked that.

Comment: Thanks very much for masking the api key, basicly i now want to pass the min and max temp to the array, such as to a text_view box, and am unsure on how to go about doing this. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey i have edited my code, it is the bit near the bottom i am struggling with parsing the temp to the txt_weather. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What problem you are facing with parsing?

Comment: Hi Debashis thanks for the reply, I have managed to parse in the data into separate text boxes, but am unsure how to parse the whole weather forecast into one text view? Thanks

Comment: If you are able to parse the individual data then you can concatenate them to a single string and then set that string to your textView.

Comment: Thanks for all fo your help :)

Comment: I have a problem. If user inputs city id randomly but not found , it will shows cod="502". How can I add code so that if not found show text as unsuccessful and resets to default value in city id not new one by using shared preference.When I close app and rerun the app, its showing new not found city id

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays and objects and make sure you have a json parser