# How to use JSON to display weather data?

Tags: java, android, json

Basically, I have designed UI/UX for a weather app, set up a remote
connection class for it for fetching data from OpenWeatherMap API:

**RemoteFetch.java:**

```
 import android.content.Context;
 
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.URL;
 
 public class RemoteFetch extends AppCompatActivity {
 
     private static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API =
             "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=9.0765&lon=7.3986&exclude=daily&appid=";
 
     public static JSONObject getJSON(Context context, String city){
         try {
             URL url = new URL(String.format(OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API, city));
             HttpURLConnection connection =
                     (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
 
             connection.addRequestProperty("x-api-key",
                     context.getString(R.string.open_weather_maps_app_id));
 
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
 
             StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder(1024);
             String tmp;
             while((tmp=reader.readLine())!=null)
                 json.append(tmp).append("\n");
             reader.close();
 
             JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.toString());
 
             // This value will be 404 if the request was not
             // successful
             if(data.getInt("cod") != 200){
                 return null;
             }
 
             return data;
         }catch(Exception e){
             return null;
         }
     }
 }
```

created a `thread` to call `getJSON` for the RemoteFetch class inside
my fragment class and If the value returned by `getJSON` is null,
should display an error message to the user:

```
 private void updateWeatherData(final String city) {
     new Thread(){
         public void run(){
             final JSONObject json = RemoteFetch.getJSON(getActivity(), city);
             if(json == null){
                 handler.post(new Runnable(){
                     public void run(){
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                 getActivity().getString(R.string.place_not_found),
                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                 });
             } else {
                 handler.post(new Runnable(){
                     public void run(){
                         renderWeather(json);
                     }
```

If it isn't, should invoke the `renderWeather` method. The
`renderWeather` method uses the JSON data to update the `TextView`
objects that I set up in my fragment class:

```
 private void renderWeather(JSONObject json){
                         try {
                             cityField.setText(json.getString("name").toUpperCase(Locale.US)) +
                                     ", " +
                                     json.getJSONObject("sys").getString("country");
                             JSONObject details = json.getJSONArray("Weather").getJSONObject(0);
                             JSONObject main = json.getJSONObject("main");
                             detailsfield.setText(
                                     details.getString("description").toUpperCase(Locale.US) +
                                             "\n" + "Humidity: " + main.getString("humidity") + "%" +
                                             "\n" + "Pressure: " + main.getString("pressure") + " hpa");
 
                             current_temp.setText(
                                     String.format("%.2f", main.getDouble("temp")) + " \\u2103");
 
                             DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                             String updatedOn = df.format(new Date(json.getLong("dt") * 1000));
                             updatedField.setText("Last update: " + updatedOn);
 
                             setcurrent_output(details.getInt("id"),
                                     json.getJSONObject("sys").getLong("sunrise") * 1000,
                                     json.getJSONObject("sys").getLong("sunset") * 1000);
 
                         }catch (Exception e){
                             Log.e("lightweatherforcast", "One or more fields not found in this JSON data");
 
 
 
                         }
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
     }.start();
 }
```

Now this is where the problem is because the tutorial I learned from used it to match their app UI but my app is different and
contains more details which I need to add from my setup, I have tried
so many methods unfailingly to match my APP UI unsuccessfully.

So far, with the weather setup, everything works fine, the only
problem is with the `renderWeather` method. I'm trying to use `JSON` to
display the weather data in the following `TextViews` currently:

```
 *`User city(cityField)`,
 *`Current time(Updated Field)`
 *`Current Temperature(current_temp)`
 *`Condition of the current temperature(current_output)`
 *`Tomorrow Temperature(small_temp1)`
 *`Condition of tomorrow's temperature(small_icon1)`
 *`Next tomorrow's temperature(small_temp2)`
 *`Condition of Next tomorrow's temperature(small_icon2)`
 *`Sunrise time(rise_time)`
 *`Sunset set(set_time)`
```

Under weather conditions panel:

```
 *`Temperature(temp_out)`
 *`Pressure(press_out)`
 *`Humidity(Humid_out)`
 *`Wind Speed(Ws_out)`
 *`Visibility(Visi_out)`
 *`UV index(UV_out)`
```

Process finished with exit code 0

This is what the JSON response looks like (formatted for readability):

```
{
   "lat":9.08,
   "lon":7.4,
   "timezone":"Africa/Lagos",
   "timezone_offset":3600,
   "current":{
      "dt":1608984165,
      "sunrise":1608961391,
      "sunset":1609003132,
      "temp":305.15,
      "feels_like":303.24,
      "pressure":1012,
      "humidity":25,
      "dew_point":282.68,
      "uvi":8.87,
      "clouds":35,
      "visibility":5000,
      "wind_speed":2.6,
      "wind_deg":150,
      "weather":[
         {
            "id":721,
            "main":"Haze",
            "description":"haze",
            "icon":"50d"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226473/discussion-on-question-by-chinez-how-to-use-json-to-display-weather-data).

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a duplicate I left the link of the link that you might find useful below.

But as a simple answer to actually represent these weather data in text as answered in that question above, then you the options to set where you want to place it in what UI you want.
The JSON Format is going to be simple, :-

```
city: {
id: 2643743,   //City ID, You may find more about these at https://openweathermap.org/find?q=
name: "London", //City Name, Just the name of your city
coord: {
lon: -0.12574,//These are coordinates for the city, Find them at google maps
lat: 51.50853
},
country: "GB", //Country names, GB here stands for United Kingdom, learn more at https://sustainablesources.com/resources/country-abbreviations/
population: 0 //Country Population
},
cod: "200",
message: 0.0268,
cnt: 5,
list: [
{
dt: 1448535600,
temp: { //Average Temperature at these times of the day (Current data is for london)
day: 8.58,
min: 8.58,
max: 9.18,
night: 9.18,
eve: 8.58,
morn: 8.58
},  //This is average temperature properties
pressure: 1025.14,
humidity: 95,
weather: [
{//Average Rain (Properties & Probabilities)
id: 500,
main: "Rain",
description: "light rain",
icon: "10d"
}
],
speed: 3.67,
deg: 224,
clouds: 92,
rain: 0.35
},
{},
{},
{},
{}
]
```

you can access these data using :-

```java
JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray forecastArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray("list");
double minTemp, maxTemp;
for(int i = 0; i < forecastArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject dailyForecast = forecastArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject tempObject = dailyForecast.getJSONObject("temp");
    minTemp = tempObject.getDouble("min");
    maxTemp = tempObject.getDouble("max");
    //add these minTemp and maxTemp to array or the 
   //way you want to use
}
```

If you find my answer weird, hard to understand or difficult, you can check the question that i embed below. Thanks.
[1]: [How to retrieve weather data in json [android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946702/how-to-retrieve-weather-data-in-json-android)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But to start with, the user of the link you referred me to only asked for temperature in the 5 daily forecasts and his setup is quite different from mine. I'm asking for city, time, temp, sunrise & sunset, weather conditions, and how to funnel them in. The answer to his question didn't solve a quarter of my issue, I need a real solution to this. I understand that you only tried to help but his issue is quite different from mine. I checked several other answers on this site before posting but none solved my issue, that's why I still decided to ask this question

Comment: @Chinez Your base URL is asking for `lat` & `lon` ...which may contradict the `city` parameter.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Okay, how to fix that please? I'm quite new

Comment: @Chinez Just remove all parameters and build up the query-string per request... not that I would have experience with that API, but common sense suggests, that one can either request by numeric coordinates - or by the name of a location.